# AMD CPU Equivalents

Tags: cpu

Could someone clarify the following:

Intel
Core 2
Core 2 Duo
Xeon
Xeon Quad Core
Core i7

What would the AMD equivalents be?  I have no particular reason for asking, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 10):

- Intel Core 2 - AMD Athlon 64
- Intel Core 2 Duo - AMD Athlon 64x2
- Intel Xeon - AMD Opteron
- Intel Core i7 - AMD Phenom 2 x4

Answer (score 6):

Go look at Tom's Hardware [cpu comparison charts](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/processors,6.html). They runs tons of tests and list many processors. A great resource for CPU's and VideoCards

Answer (score 1):

[Opteron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opteron) is the Xeon equivalent as this tends to be for server or other high-end systems.

Core i7 is Intel's latest architecture so the closest AMD equivalent would be ["Phenom II"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenom_II)

Answer (score 1):

Core 2 Duo would be equivalent to Athlon X2,the both are dual-core,but there are sure some differences in performance